# Eigenpairs of $(I + p_k (A)A)^t A (I + p_k (A)A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let ${λ_i, v_i }$ $i = 1, 2, . . . , n$ be the eigenpairs of the symmetric matrix $A$. Show that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $(I + p_k (A)A)^t A (I + p_k (A)A)$ are $λ_i [1+λ_i p_k(λ_i )]^2$ and $vi$ , respectively.

I started by decomposing $(I + p_k (A)A)^t A (I + p_k (A)A)$, but that leads me nowhere. I think more tricks and techniques are required to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $p_k$ is a polynomial, you have (since $A$ is symmetric) that $$(I+p_k(A)A)^tA(I+p_k(A)A)=A(I+p_k(A)A)^2=q(A),$$ where $q(x)=x(1+xp_k(x))^2.$

It is an easy, general fact that the eigenpairs of $q(A)$  are $q(\lambda_i)$, $v_i$.